# How to Create Tab Bar  Using PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm trying to develope the most native looking iPhone application by using phonegap and the tab bar is really getting on my nerves.
How can I have the native iPhone tab bar at the bottom of the screen using Phonegap?
And Also i have big truoble for choosing framework for phonegap.I want to create lots of parsing and sutch more things such as native app.So Please help me which will be the best framework for phonegap.

Please if anybody knows then please replyme.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JQueryMobile does not include a native like Tab bar feature.

The closest JQueryMobile feature to a native tab bar would be the toolbars

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-bars.html

You may want to consider looking at appML, which is a framework based on JQTouch and JQuery.  appML includes native like tab bars

http://www.appml.org/